# CRM 2011 - Compare years in LINQ Query - Gives an error : Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I've tried several methods to compare years in a date, but each time I'm getting the "Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."-error!

The methods I've used :

```
var openInvoices = orgContext.CreateQuery<Invoice>().Where(i => i.SKY_InvoiceDate.Value.Year == 2010);
var openInvoices = orgContext.CreateQuery<Invoice>().Where(i => i.GetAttributeValue<DateTime?>("SKY_InvoiceDate".ToLower()).Value.Year == 2011); 
var openInvoices = orgContext.CreateQuery<Invoice>().Where(i => i.SKY_InvoiceDate.Value.Year.Equals(2010));
```

IS there a way where I can get all the invoices for the year 2011?

Thx for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the call to the Year property of DateTime can't be translated properly.  A simple workaround:

```
var openInvoices = orgContext.CreateQuery<Invoice>()
    .Where(i =>
        i.SKY_InvoiceDate.Value >= new DateTime(2010, 1, 1)
        && i.SKY_InvoiceDate.Value < new DateTime(2011, 1, 1));
```